# why Array Index Out Of Bound Exception while re arranging doc file paragraph?

Tags: for-loop, ms-word, doc, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is a code snippet. Its giving arrayindexoutofboundexception. dont know why ?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextParagraph;


public class wordcount 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{


        File file = new File("E:\\myFiles\\abc.doc");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
        WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
        String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();

        for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++)
            {  

               // System.out.println(fileData[i].toString());
                String[] paraword = fileData[i].toString().split(" ");
               // out.println(paraword.length);

                if(paraword[i].length() == 0 )
                {
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
                else if(paraword[i].length() > 0 && paraword[i].length() < 12)
                {
                    for(int k=0 ; k < paraword[i].length()-1 ; k++)
                    {
                       System.out.println(paraword[k].toString());
                    }
                }
                else if(paraword[i].length() >= 12  )
                {
                    for(int k=0 ; k < 12 ; k++)
                    {
                       System.out.println(paraword[k].toString());
                    }
                }


               System.out.println("\n");

            }

}
}
```

This is the image of the abc.doc file

[image: this is the abc.doc]

Note : Expected output will be printed on java console.

and the output will contain 12 words in each line. But after executing first line the error occurs.

Any help would be appreciated

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not familiar with the apache.org API, but just by looking at your logic it looks like you want to replace every instance of:

`paraword[i].length()`

with:

```
paraword.length
```

Because it looks like you want to check how many words are in the paragraph and not how long the first word of the paragraph is. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that will fix you up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed `paraword[i].length()` with `paraword.length` , and Array index out of bound problem has solved. But its printing only 12 words for the paragraph with more than 12 words.

Comment: If you trying to get words to print on the same line you need to use the `System.out.print()` method rather than `System.out.println()`. If you use `System.out.println("\n")` it should give you two lines rather than just one. To get it to write all the lines in the paragraph, it'll be more complicated, and I'd have to think about it more.

Comment: Thanks Amy. The problem is solved. I am posting the modified code in below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code snippet

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class ExtractWordDocument
{
public String myString() throws IOException
  {
      File file = new File("PATH FOR THE .doc FILE");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
        WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
        String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();

        ArrayList<Object> EntireDoc = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++)
            {  
                String[] paraword = fileData[i].toString().split("\\s+");
                if(paraword.length == 0 )
                    {EntireDoc.add("\n");}
                else if(paraword.length > 0 && paraword.length < 12)
                    {
                    for(int k=0 ; k < paraword.length ; k++)
                        {EntireDoc.add(paraword[k].toString()+" ");}
                    }
                else if(paraword.length > 12  )
                    {
                    java.util.List<String> arrAsList = Arrays.asList(paraword);
                    String formatedString = arrAsList.toString()
                                             .replace(",", "")  //remove the commas
                                             .replace("[", "")   //remove the right bracket
                                             .replace("]", ""); //remove the left bracket

                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(formatedString);
                     int i1 = 0;
                     while ((i1 = sb.indexOf(" ", i1 + 75)) != -1)
                        {sb.replace(i1, i1 + 1, "\n");}
                     EntireDoc.add(sb.toString());
                    }

               EntireDoc.add("\n");
             }

            String formatedString = EntireDoc.toString()
                                             .replace(",", "")  //remove the commas
                                             .replace("[", "")   //remove the right bracket
                                             .replace("]", ""); //remove the left bracket

        return formatedString;
  }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try{
    System.out.print(new ExtractWordDocument().myString());
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){System.out.print(ioe);}

}

}
```

Note : This code will not print 12 words in each line but 75 charecters in each line.